# TFDTable/TFDQuery on blob null - provide alternative image

Tags: delphi, firedac

Is there a way to configure my TFDTable/TFDQuery such that whenever BLOB in a table record is Null,
i have a chance to provide another Blob/photo.

I looked through TField events for blob, but there seems to be no suitable event.

Setup: Delphi 10.4, MySQL, using FMX framework

Comment: Would be nice if you add your request and tell which database engine your are using.

Comment: Do you want to save the alternate image to the database, or just display it?

Comment: @fpiette I'm using Firedac with MySQL... apologies, I didn't know this issue would be database-dependent.

Comment: @JohnEasley apologies for late reply as I didn't realise there were comments in original post.  I would like to display it only.

Comment: Why can you handle that case with Delphi code when you use the data from SQL result set? Why do you move your images in the database? Would be much easier if you always let the image in a file and put the filename in the database.

Comment: @fpiette, I'm using server to serve out Json via http(s) to client. so it's simpler for me to include the image in json.

Comment: As I understand you, the result set is transformed to JSON. So you have a loop in your delphi code to construct the JSON and the serve that JSON. In the loop, you can check if the blob field is NULL and the supply a given image from a file instead. If you show the code you use (Edit your question), you'll get a better answer. No need to show the actual application code but a simple working example reproducing the problem you have. Just executing the query, building the JSON and displaying the JSON in a TMemo. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @fpiette, your point is taken. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a CalcField or InternalCalcField to your dataset and in the OnCalcFields() handler check if the blob field is empty. In that case, fill with your 'alternative' data.

Then in the rest of your application refer to the InternalCalcField field instead of the original one.

You do not specify where that data should come from, so you'll have to figure that out yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Data will come from a file... loadfromfile.  do you have a short sample code on how you usually do this?  So no difference in performance/functionality whether using Calc or InternalCalc?